# PDF generated from web app only shows google login page, am I missing an authorization?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made a simple html web app (to get more complex later), and need to a script to download a copy as a pdf.  When I run the script to generate the pdf, I can't get it to show anything other than the google login page.

I have toggled all options for the web app.  I have also gone through a few different ways to generate the pdf, as well as generating a doc, which also didn't work.

```
function htmlToPDF() {

  var html = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbztkYQGmAowe21IITtpaUVsTwuNdbLmRC_B4opqp9A/exec" ;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(html);  
  var htmlBody = response.getContentText();

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(response, "text/html", "text.html");
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");

  DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");
}
```

Here's an example of the PDF I get.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P-uK4-nhXA76tkpqABOK-xnoTnra9-4M/view?usp=sharing

Web app code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_68bbc"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "2",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "hide_top_toolbar": true,
  "range": "all",
  "save_image": false,
  "container_id": "tradingview_68bbc"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

I re-deployed, and now I get this mostly blank pdf:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gz3Sy0UXhpxHwwTUzFCFoDkwRrofd4g7

Comment: Show your web app code.

Comment: Added code.  Right now, it's just holding an embedded graph.  I will be adding more from sheet, and styling it etc.

Comment: And Your doGet() code?

Comment: now you have it all!

Comment: Your publish settings? Execute as?

Comment: I have tried all variations, with the same result.

Comment: Try Execute as "me", Access:"Anyone even anonymous"

Comment: @TheMaster Still can't get it to work.  New Web app url  https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw-cnBtuwf546onpONqkTlvzrsa01ABDJDDCb4L/exec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You had two issues**

1. You had authorization problems because of not deploying the script as public - you solved this issue now.
2. The website contents are not displayed correctly in the pdf you create.

### The latter issue is a tricky one

> The problem is that your web site contents are rendered dynamically in the browser and cannot be captured with the UrlFetchApp.

You need to use a workaround, e.g. call with UrlFetchApp an external API that would take a screenshot of the browser contents and pass them as an image to Apps Script.